# Why does Chrome raise a mousemove on mousedown?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have noticed that in Chrome (I'm using Chrome 35.0.1916.114 [**UPDATE**: also occurs in "35.0.1916.153 m"], Windows 7 64-bit) when I click the left button not only is a mouseDown event raised (as I expect) but also a mouseMove.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtMh4/2/) if you click in the input element you will see a 'D' for each mouseDown event raised and an 'M' for each mouseMove.

HTML:

```
<input id="txt" type="text"/>
<p>Moves</p><p id="moves">0</p>
<p>Downs</p><p id="downs">0</p>
<p id="activity">Activity</p>
```

JS:

```
$( "#txt" ).mousedown(function() {
     document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML +="D";
    update(false,true);
});
$( "#txt" ).mousemove(function() {
    document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML +="M";
    update(true,false);
});

function update(move, down) 
{
    var moves=document.getElementById("moves").innerHTML;
    if (move) 
    {
        moves ++;
        document.getElementById("moves").innerHTML=moves;
    }

    var downs=document.getElementById("downs").innerHTML;
    if (down) 
    {
        downs ++;
        document.getElementById("downs").innerHTML=downs;
    }
    var d=parseInt(downs);
    var m=parseInt(moves);
    if ((d+m)%25==0)
    {
        document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML +="<br>";
    }
}
```

In FF and IE11 once the cursor is in the input element then you will be able to get consecutive 'D's (ie, a click raises a single mouseDown event). In Chrome each mouse click raises a mouseDown and two mouseMove events.

This is not due to any slight wobbling of the mouse as I use a trackball so the cursor is absolutely stationary.

Is anyone aware of a workaround for this?

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Maybe Chrome considers depressing the mouse button a "movement" since you're moving the mouse button and the mouse switch... ... ... never mind.

Comment: Does not happen in my version of Chrome: 35.0.1916.153 (Official Build 274914) on Linux

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I am on "35.0.1916.153 m" and it happens as described above. My colleague is on the same version and when using a mouse (not a trackball) each mouseDown is accompanied by one (not two) mouseMoves. What input device are you using?

Comment: @Badgerspot A regular crappy mouse. Maybe it's OS dependent? I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Store the mouse position in the onmove handler. If you get another onmove event fired, where the current coords are the same as last time, you know that it's a click, not a move.

Comment: I can certainly replicate using latest Chrome (35.0.1916.153 m) and Windows 8.  A lot of discussion on the web but no concrete solutions. I think it must be a jQuery / Chrome issue may be worth submitting a bug.  For reference I'm using a trackpad so there's no way the mouse is moving.

Comment: This irritating issue is still occurring today, with the latest Chrome (43.0.2357.124 m).

Comment: Is this still an issue? And in case, has anybody opened a bug in [Chrome's bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)? Otherwise it's possible that Chrome devs are not even aware of it!

Comment: @FabioTurati - Bug here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161464

Comment: Have the same issue on Chrome version 91.0.4472.164 & Win 7. After the Win restart it works normal again, it's a very strange problem.

Answer (score 5):

strange issue indeed, however with a little flag this can be circumvented: http://jsfiddle.net/3a28p7ek/

the change is pretty straight forward, setting `ignoreNextMove` to `true` on each mouse down and canceling the move handler if this flag is set, after resetting the flag so that regular move events get handled properly:

```
ignoreNextMove = false;

$( "#txt" ).mousedown(function() {
    ignoreNextMove = true;
    document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML +="D";    
    update(false,true);
});
$( "#txt" ).mousemove(function() {
        if(ignoreNextMove)
    {
        ignoreNextMove = false;
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("activity").innerHTML +="M";
    update(true,false);
});
```

Comment: should work, but i hoped to find an answer which is more satisfying